# What is the java extesions path on linux?

Tags: java, linux, mysql-connector, liquibase

I need to put some jar files into extensions directory so I do not have to provide --classpath. I wonder what is the extension path in linux systems ?

Basically I need to put `mysql-connector-java.jar` which is currently under `/usr/share/java` and each time I run `liquibase` migration tool it give classpath error. I may provide classpath argument with liquibase but putting `mysql-connector-java.jar` in shared/extensions directory seems more straight forward ( if there is any)

Please guide me

Comment: may be this question best suites in askubuntu.com

Comment: Have you tried this system property? java.ext.dirs  Something like this: `-Djava.ext.dirs=YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH` Also, perhaps (I have never done it) it could work by default in Linux using this directory: `/usr/java/packages/lib/ext`  See: [Installed Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)

Comment: @Gooseman let me check that

Comment: there is no such directory `/usr/java/packages/lib/ext`

Comment: @sakhunzai In my machine I can not find it either. AFAIK your only options  would be either to create the missing directory or to use the system property `java.ext.dirs`

Comment: how to get `java.ext.dirs path` . Are you suggesting to set one ?

Comment: @sakhunzai Right, I am suggesting to set one. I guess you have downloaded liquibase tar.gz file from here: [liquibase download](http://www.liquibase.org/download/). The tar.gz file contains the liquibase shell script. In that case, you could try to run liquibase like this: `./liquibase -Djava.ext.dirs=YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH` and see if it works for you.

Comment: that is what I wanted to avoid liquibase has `--classpath` argument which works fine. My intension was put the mysql connector jar in extension directory so I dont have to pass path with --classpath

Comment: under Mac OSx I have put the mysql jconnector under `/System/Library/Java/Extensions/` which works perfect